# NSOutlineView get flipped in 10.9 when click on it

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have a cell based `NSOutlineView` in that I have sub classed the `NSTextfieldCell` and I had written following code.

```
-(void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {

    // A single cell instance is used to render every row, so we can't store the 
    // custom view here

    NSRect bgFrame = cellFrame;
    bgFrame.size.width = bgFrame.size.width + bgFrame.origin.x + 3;
    bgFrame.origin.x = 0;

    if ([self isHighlighted])
    {
        [[NSColor blackColor] set];  
        NSRectFill(bgFrame);
    }
    else
    {
        NSGradient *gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor whiteColor] endingColor:[NSColor lightGrayColor]];
        [gradient drawInRect:bgFrame angle:90];
    }


    [controller showViews:controlView frame:bgFrame highlight:[self isHighlighted] && !isEditing];
}
```

In View controller

```
-(void)showViews:(NSView*)parent frame:(NSRect)cellFrame highlight:(BOOL)highlight
{
    NSView* nestedView;
    nestedView = menu100;
   [nestedView setFrame: cellFrame];

    if ([nestedView superview] != parent)
    {
        [nestedView prepareContentInRect:[nestedView visibleRect]];
        [parent addSubview: nestedView];
    }

}

 nestedView = menu100; menu100 is a `NSView` with `NSOutlineview`
```

menu100 view
 [image]

In `NSOutlineView`

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {

    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
              [cell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor keyboardFocusIndicatorColor]];

    }
    else
    {
        if (item!=nil) {

            CustomCellController* cellCtrl = [cellViewControllers objectForKey:item];
            if (!cellCtrl)
            {
                cellCtrl = [[CustomCellController alloc] initWithMenu:item];
                [cellViewControllers setObject:cellCtrl forKey:item];
            }
            CustomCell* mycell = cell;
            [mycell setController:cellCtrl];
        }
    }
}
```

now the view is look like this 
   [image: before clicking]

Now when I click on child outline view it become flipped.
[image]

The above code is working in 10.8 but it is get flipped in 10.9. I am become mad on this. Can any one give suggestion to get rid of this in 10.9.

Comment: Looks kinda cool, though 8-)